# How to add selected item into mysql database Laravel Schema Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.1, laravel-schema-builder

I used [webpatser/laravel-countries](https://packagist.org/packages/webpatser/laravel-countries)

in my controlleer

```
$countries= DB::table('countries')->lists('name');
```

to select country list in my form i got all the country

```
{!! Form::select('country',$countries,null) !!}
```

in my schema now i have like this

```
$table->string('country');
```

i can select the country but when i submit country column blank. any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit 2:

Your insert need to look like this:

```
DB::table('users')->insert(
    ['country' => 'Canada']
);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#inserts

---

Edit: if you want to submit the string of the country name then you need the string to be the key in your array. Like this:

```
$countries= DB::table('countries')->lists('name', 'name');
```

That's not typical use of a database relationship though. I'd expect the user table to have a country_id integer field that matches the id field in countries. That's what my original answer (below) covers.

---

Original:

You'll want the id in your $countries array. I bet right now your ids are off by one, starting at 0 instead of 1 like in your DB.

```
$countries= DB::table('countries')->lists('name', 'id');
```

There are different ways to save relations in laravel, but I actually prefer to skip that when possible and save directly to the country_id field.

```
{!! Form::select('country_id',$countries,null) !!}
```

But that depends on how your relationship is setup. And how you're saving. Show all the code!

Comment: i tried both way but the problem is inserting data `$table->string('country');` here only something rong

Comment: OH you don't want it to be a relationship, you want to save the country string in your table? What is the table you're inserting into? Are you using an eloquent model? Do you have a fillable or guarded array?

Comment: Did you run the migration to add that column to your table?

Comment: i used webpatser/laravel-countries package for country list for i dont use Eloquent model . when i use this package i can have countires table so i can use that table

Comment: `Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id'); $table->string('country');
});`

Comment: That's in your migration? What does your insert look like?

Comment: my country column is empty when i save this.

Comment: thankyou my mistake $table->string('country'); shd be $table->integer('country'); :) :) :) edit your answer like this i will approve :)